# Nest Js Conditional Class validator creating empty object in Swagger

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I have a situation where I need to add an either-or validation.

Basically I have an object like `UuidOrName`. Any one - either name or uuid should be present.

So this is what I tried out:

```js
export class UuidOrNameReference {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @ValidateIf((o) => !o.name || o.uuid)
  /**
   * The object's instance UUID
   */
  uuid?: string;

  /**
   * The object's instance name
   */
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @ValidateIf((o) => !o.uuid || o.name)
  name?: string;
}
```

This is used like this way in my DTO:

```js
  @ValidateNested()
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => UuidOrNameReference)
  public service_policy?: UuidOrNameReference;
```

Now it is working functionally correct.

However how can I specify it in swagger such that by looking at the schema in swagger one can get an idea of either or is the constraint?

Currently the swagger is shown like this `service_policy` field:

[image]

I want to add some schema like description such that looking at the Schema one can get an idea about the constraint.

Please note: I am using NestJs [CLI_plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin).
My `nest-cli.json` looks like this (relevant section only):

```json
    "app1": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/app1",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/app1/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/app1/tsconfig.app.json",
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
            "options": {
              "dtoFileNameSuffix": [".models.ts", ".model.ts", ".dto.ts"],
              "controllerFileNameSuffix": ".controller.ts",
              "classValidatorShim": true,
              "introspectComments": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Any pointer will be appreciated.